# How to delete list items with buttons at certain indexes HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

MY HTML list has buttons inside that are supposed to delete THAT list item, except it is instead deleing the item on the bottom of the list. I've tried get the list unique ID but it is not working.
Each item of the list has a unique ID like so, "item1" , "item2" ...  .

I also need the index of the list to delete the actual item in the object of the list or else they all just get stuck in there and it's no good.

If anyone has dealt with this before, please help me out. I put everything in a codepen so it's easy to see what I am talking about.

Here is the code for deleting list items

```
function deleteIndex() {
    var idString = "item"+ toDoListObject.objectIndex;
  document.getElementById(idString).outerHTML = "";
    toDoListObject.objectIndex -= 1;
}
```

and here is the todolistobject

```
var toDoListObject = {
    list: [],
    objectIndex: 0
}
```

Other code is in the code pen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqKaJj

Any help would mean so much, I am eager to learn and really want to get to know how to make JS on the client side.

Comment: _"Other code is in the code pen"_ - Everything required to reproduce the problem has to be part of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

deleteIndex() needs to accept an element parameter; you are passing it in as an argument here:

```
 insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li id=' + idString + ' onclick="deleteIndex(this)">'+ myThing+'  <button>x</button></li>');
```

so you'll need to accept it as a parameter:

```
function deleteIndex(item) {
  document.getElementById('toDo').removeChild(item);
}
```

The only thing you'll need to do now is remove the item from `todoListObject.items[]`.

Also, `todoListObject.objectIndex` is acting more as a *length* than an index, but the length can be derived from `todoListObject.items.length`. Consider the data structure you'll need and why before implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove()` to remove the child. Having said that there are couple of few  more steps where logical change is required.

Push the id of the `li` inside the array. So on deleting the `li` remove that `id` from the array. Also instead check if the length of the array is greater that 5, instead of checking incremented value of the `objectIndex`.

Beside you are already passing context of `this` with `onclick` so you can get the element inside click handler

```js
//Make a todolistObject
//Add functions to add an activity object to an array
//Make the activity object, taking name and category

var toDoListObject = {
  list: [],
  objectIndex: 0
}

function addActivity() {
  //changed here
  if (toDoListObject.list.length > 5) {
    window.alert("you've reached your max number of activities");
    return;
  }
  var myThing = document.getElementById("activityNamer").value;
  if (myThing == "") {
    window.alert("add an activity name");
    return;
  }
  toDoListObject.objectIndex += 1;
  var idString = "item" + toDoListObject.objectIndex;
  //changed here
  toDoListObject.list.push(idString);
  document.getElementById('toDo').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li id=' + idString + ' onclick="deleteIndex(this)">' + myThing + '  <button>x</button></li>');
  var myThing = document.getElementById("activityNamer").value = "";
}

function deleteIndex(elem) {
  //remove the deleted item from the array 
  toDoListObject.list = toDoListObject.list.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== elem.id;
  });
  elem.remove();
}

function checkForEnter() {
  document.getElementById('activityNamer').onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      addActivity();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.mainBody {
  height: 300px;
}

.mainBody ul {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">To do list testing</h1>
<div class="mainBody">
  <ul id="toDo">

  </ul>
</div>
Activity Name<input type="text" name="activityName" id="activityNamer" onKeyDown="checkForEnter()"><br>
<button id="activityButton" onclick="addActivity()">Insert activity</button>
```